# Cannot connect to mysql localhost

Tags: mysql, apache

I am a neewbie to Mac and web development.I have installed Apache and the web server is working just fine. When I type localhost, it says "It Works". Also I am able to connect to company's database via workbench.

But when I try to create a local connection using hostname: 127.0.0.1 it says: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO). I am not sure if in resolving this issue whether I changed the password or not.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: This is not really a programming question, or an Apache question. It looks like you are just seeking a tutorial on how to use MySQL. Try specifying a password.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your firewall to allow other machines to access the PC running Apache. For OSX: http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-enable-web-sharing-in-os-x-mountain-lion/

You can find the IP address of your Apache machine by pressing Start, type cmd. In the command window type: `ipconfig /all` EDIT: just realized you mentioned you were on Mac, use this link to find your IP: http://www.wikihow.com/Find-Your-IP-Address-on-a-Mac

When you have the IP of your Apache machine and set the firewall up to allow Apache to get through on likely port 80, you can access it from other PC's or devices on your local network: http://192.168.1.123/ for example if that's your IP.

127.0.0.1 is the local-loopback IP. Specifically for OSX this would directly answer your question: https://superuser.com/questions/512786/why-does-localhost-and-127-0-0-1-resolve-to-different-locations-on-mac-osc-10-8

Answer (score 0):

I'm with the same problem time ago, you need to give privileges to the users to connect to the localhost, is different localhost from apache to mysql permissions

Possibly a security precaution. You could try adding a new administrator account:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'yorsh'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'yorsh'@'localhost'
->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql> CREATE USER 'yorsh'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'yorsh'@'%'
->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: this sounds more like a comment than an answer